# SQLite How to calculate a difference between two variables of the same table

Tags: sql, sqlite, sum, aggregate-functions, unpivot

I am pretty new to SQL and I can't figure out how to sum the amounts (in_amount - out_amount) per asset in the pantry considering the following table. [image: Table]

Ideally I would get
[this result table (calculation between parentheses for clarification)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGPoL.png) 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.  The question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like  `union all` to unpivot, then aggregation:

```
select asset, sum(amount) total_amount
from (
    select in_asset as asset, in_amount as amount from mytable
    union all
    select out_asset, - out_amount from mytable
) t
group by asset
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @GMB! Exactly what I was trying to do.